# Nested React Router doesn't render component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, nested-routes

I have a problem in nested routing in React.js.

The presenter component has this.

```
<Route
    exact
    path={`/course/${id}/assignment`}
    render={(props) => (
        <CourseAssignments
            {...props}
            courseId={id}
            data={assignmentData}
        />
    )}
/>
```

And here is `CourseAssignments` component at `/course/${id}/assignment`.

```
const CourseAssignments: React.FC<RouteComponentProps & IProps> = ({
  courseId,
  data,
  match,
}) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Route
        exact
        path={match.path}
        render={(props) => (
          <AssignmentList {...props} courseId={courseId} data={data} />
        )}
      />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={AssignmentSubmit} />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

The `AssignmentList` renders well at `course/0/assignment`.

```
const AssignmentList: React.FC<RouteComponentProps & IProps> = ({
  match,
  courseId,
  data,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((d) => (
        <div key={d.id}>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/${d.id}`}>{d.title}</Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I use `<Link />`, it links to `course/0/assignment/:id`.

But `course/0/assignment/1` doesn't render `AssignmentSubmit` component.

I don't know why it doesn't work. Pleaze help.

(env is localhost)

Comment: Seems like since `/course/${id}/assignment` route has `exact` attribute it doesn't match 
`course/0/assignment/1` so it doesn't render `CourseAssignments` so no `AssignmentSubmit`

Comment: Thanks @AlexChashin, I solved it!!